# Android: different layouts which have elements with the same exact IDs - works but why?

Tags: android, resources

I was working on an app tonight and I noticed that I have two similar activities which have different layouts (mylayout1.xml and mylayout2.xml)... but within those layouts I have some elements that are identical, right down to their ids ("@+id/mybutton" in each layout file).

When I setContentView(R.layout.mylayout1) in an activity and then findViewById(R.id.mybutton) to perform setOnClickListener(), how does Android "know" which button I'm really referring to when I finally click it?

Everything seems to work just fine, with the appropriate callbacks triggering (and not, so far as I can tell, going to the wrong activity - though only one is on-screen at a time in my tests so far (e.g., dialog-type activities). It just occurs to me (as I noticed this duplication during unrelated work) that maybe this is working simply by chance rather than design. OTOH, if Android is being smart about it, I won't worry as long as more than one instance of such an element is never on-screen at the same time (such as OK buttons).

Comment: because in your onCreate you are inflating diff. layouts so those ids are searched in that layouts only

Comment: I'm getting the feeling this was a pretty basic question... perhaps I didn't search on the correct terms because I didn't find answers as clear as these here. I appreciate the quick and accurate reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are calling setContentView the view hierarchy from XML is parsed and created. When you then search for a View with a specific id android will look into that view hierarchy and search for a view with that matching id. So you will never end up with a view element which is defined in some other .xml file with the same id because these view elements are not part of the activities view hierarchy.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the setContentView(View) method sets, as stands int the doc, the activity content to an explicit view, and finbViewById(int id) refers to the view object you set with setContentView. As matter of fact, if you refer an element in a layout that you do not properly set, the application crash with null pointer exception...

Comment: I noticed that null pointer thing just a couple of minutes ago... I didn't make the connection til now. Thanks!